# Joining K3s agent node to K8s Master node

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, k3s

I was curious if we can use k8s and k3s together as it will help me in solving a complex architecture for edge computing.

I have a running k8s cluster prepared using kubeadm. For edge devices, I would like to have lightweight k3s running on them. Is it possible to use k8s cluster control plane to control k3s agent running on edge devices (embedded/routers etc)?

This kind of setup will open a lot of options for me as I'll have k8s functionality with k3s light footprint.
I tried using the default token of kubeadm k8s on k3s agent node (worker) but obviously it didn't join.

Answer (score 1):

Kubeadm join internally performs TLS bootstrap of kubelet on worker nodes.You will have to [TLS bootstrap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/) the kubelet on k3s worker nodes to join the cluster created by kubeadm.